# Django 3.2 - querie multiple Models in view (SQL comparison)

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, multi-model-database

I'm quite new to django and have problems with the ORM and the view-queries.
We have already migrated and synched some Models from our productive DB to the django DB, but I have problems with connecting two Models to each other.

e.g. models.py:

```
class SsdgSendung(models.Model):
    sdg_sdgid = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=30)
    sdg_konz = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'ssdg_sendung'

class SsdaSdgadr(models.Model):
    sda_sdgid = models.ForeignKey(SsdgSendung, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    sda_satid = models.CharField(max_length=4, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'ssda_sdgadr'
        unique_together = (('sda_sdgid', 'sda_satid'),)
```

## Sample Data

SsdgSendung:

- sdg_sdgid = BL-1237781-BL-1
- sdg_konz = 009874

SsdaSdgadr:

- sdg_sdgid = BL-1237781-BL-1
- sda_satid = IV
- sdg_sdgid = BL-1237781-BL-1
- sda_satid = CN

How should the correct "django"-query look for this equivalent SQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
   SsdgSendung 
   inner join SsdaSdgadr on sdg_sdgid = sda_sdgid and sda_satid = 'IV' 
WHERE 
   sdg_konz = '1234'
```

I tried this, but I don't get any result on the template:

```
Sendungen = SsdgSendung.objects.filter(sdg_konz = current_user_konz).order_by('-sdg_datum').prefetch_related('sda_sdgid')
```

template

```
{% for la_item in SDG_Overview %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ la_item.sdg_sdgid }}</td> <!-- works well -->
    <td>{{ la_item.sda_satid }}</td> <!-- don't work -->
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sendungen=SsdaSdgadr.objects.filter(sda_sdgid__sdg_konz=current_user_konz).order_by('-sdg_datum')
```

template

```
    {% for la_item in SDG_Overview %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ la_item.sdg_sdgid.sdg_sdgid }}</td> <!-- works well -->
    <td>{{ la_item.sda_satid }}</td> <!-- will work -->
</tr>
```

This should work  [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/#many-to-one-relationships)

Comment: So far I got it, in my interface-job we go always from the top → down:
From this point of view the Master-Model would be "SsdgSendung.sdg_sdgid" and the related Model "SsdaSdgadr"

From django view, it seems only to work from bottom to up.
Like: SsdaSdgadr (which is Children from SsdgSendung) related to SsdgSendung

Is this is this assumption correct?

Comment: I am not able to understand your argument perfectly. But as you need sda_satid field you need an object of that table so yes from children you can fetch the parent. I don't know to way to fetch children from parents. But the above answer should work. please upvote if it did.

Comment: This solution works well, when the querie is build from child-model 
I used this complex-lookup to get the desired result:
`Sendungen = SsdaSdgadr.objects.filter(Q(sda_sdgid__sdg_konz=current_user_konz)&Q(sda_satid="IV")).order_by('-sda_sdgid__sdg_datum')`